# Hide notification bar (Status bar) when play Youtube Video in Fragment

Tags: android-fragments, notifications, statusbar, android-youtube-api

I have a Fragment in Activity full screen size. In this fragment, I add one Fragment that extends YouTubePlayerSupportFragment to play Youtube video. When Video is playing, notification bar (status bar) appears, I don't want that. I want my app always Full Screen View. Please tell me how to fix it